# laravel filter collection based on relation

Tags: php, laravel, collections

Assuming the following code to represent an order and the related transactions:

order

```
public function transactions(){

    return $this->hasMany('App\Transaction');
}
```

already loaded collection (`$orders`)

```
order1
    id
    amount
    transactions (relation)
        txid
        method
        amount

order2
    id
    amount
    transactions (relation)
        txid
        method
        amount
```

The following filtering on already loaded collection does not work as expected:

```
                    $isNotEmpty = $orders->filter(function ($order) use ($receivingPayment) {
            return $order->transactions->txid === $receivingPayment->txid && $order->transactions->method === $receivingPayment->method;
          })->isNotEmpty();
```

It seems like the filtering on the relation `transactions` doesn't work this way?
It returns an empty element even if the transaction id is in the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't or don't want to use the answers above and keep working with the collection you've got, use a combination of `filter` and `pluck`:

```
$orders->filter(function ($order) use ($receivingPayment) {
    return $order->transactions
        ->pluck('id')
        ->containsStrict($receivingPayment->txid);
})
```

To filter for multiple conditions matching a single transaction, use a combination of multiple `where`'s and `isNotEmpty()`:

```
$orders->filter(function ($order) use ($receivingPayment) {
    return $order->transactions
        ->where('txid', $receivingPayment->txid)
        ->where('method', $receivingPayment->method)
        ->isNotEmpty();
})
```

Comment: Using relations inside `where` collection method isn't possible?

Comment: In your case `transactions` is an array containing multiple transactions and not a single one (so the most logic thing to do would be using `transactions.*.txid` as an argument but unfortunately Laravel does not support this syntax). But this still returns a collection which you can use to check with `isNotEmpty()` if it contains any values.

Comment: `transactions` is an array / collection itself, could you show an example how to check?

Comment: My answer is the example. You can use relations and access relations' properties inside `where` but only if it's a single relation (like `hasOne` or `belongsTo`) but not if they're inside a collection (like for instance `hasMany`).

Comment: Thank you. Is there a simple way how I can include `method` for an additional check inside the `filter()` method? So I can include a check for the payment method too?

Comment: You'd have to filter the transactions like `return $order->transactions->filter(fn ($transaction) => $transaction->txid === $receivingPayment->txid && $transaction->method === 'somemethod')->isNotEmpty()` or use multiple `where()`'s.

Comment: I've added an example. Ignore the additional `filter` example from my comment above. It's crap.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of filtering orders, you wanted to filter transactions. You can do that like this:

```php
$orders->transactions()->where('transactions.txid', '=', $receivingPayment->txid)->get();
```

Comment: I want to filter the collection, not on query base. Data is already fetched from database.

Answer (score 0):

You should try whereHas instead.

```
$orders->whereHas('transactions', function($query) use ($receivingPayment) { $query->where('txid', '=' $receivingPayment->txid})->count();
```

If there is nothing found, than you should doubleCheck if there no missmatch with $receivingPayment id in database.

Comment: I want to filter the collection, not on query base. Data is already fetched from database.